# In Ambari, If there is no directory from mentioned in datanode.data.dir, its creating it on the root drive

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have 3 data nodes A, B, C. A and B contain 3 hard drives mounted as

```
/hadoop/data1
/hadoop/data2
/hadoop/data3
```

In C node, I have only 2 drives mounted

```
/hadoop/data1
/hadoop/data2
```

I have installed HDFS with

```
datanode.data.dir = /hadoop/data1,/hadoop/data2,/hadoop/data3
```

Ambari installation says that the data directory which is not present will be ignored.

But in my case, a new folder(/hadoop/data3) is created under root drive in node C.

How can I make it ignore the non-existent directory?

Answer (score 0):

I created and assigned a new Host Config Group to the node C.

I then added only the required data node directories to the newly created host config group.

The tutorial can be found in this link:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/56163/machines-with-various-disk-numbers.html
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.2.2/bk_ambari-operations/content/using_host_config_groups.html